# Vector derivate of a composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I am having some difficulties solving the following problem:

---

Let $h: R^{2} \to R^{2}$ a function of class $C^{2}$ and let $f(x, y) = h(x^{2} + y^{2}, x^{3} + y)$.

Determine a non null vector, $v \in R²$, such that $\frac{\partial f} {\partial v} (0, 1) = 0$

---

Here's how I attempted to do it.

Consider $g(x, y) = (x^{2} + y^{2}, x^{3} + y)$ we have that $f(x, y) = (h \circ g) (x, y)$.
Since $h$ and $g$ are of class $C^{2}$ so is $f$ and thus we can conclude that $\frac{\partial f} {\partial v} (0, 1) = Dh({g(0,1)}) Dg(0,1) v$.

Given that g(0, 1) = (1, 1), we have
$$ Dh(1,1) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (x,y) & \frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (x,y)\\
\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (x,y) & \frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (x,y)
\end{bmatrix} _ {| (1, 1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) & \frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1,1)\\
\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) & \frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1,1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$ Dg(0,1) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2x & 2y\\
3x^{2} & 1
\end{bmatrix} _ {| (0,1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Doing the matrix multiplication I end up with
$$
\frac{\partial f} {\partial v} (0, 1) =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1, 1)\\
0& 2\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1, 1)
\end{bmatrix} v = 0.
$$
This is where I get stuck, because the result of this operation will result in a "vector" in R² and the expected result is 0?

Any help is appreciated! I did it like this, and it's likely wrong, because I was having trouble understanding how to apply the chain rule to vector derivatives, I also have no access to the solution or resolution from the source.

### Solution:

Thanks to all the replies I managed to understand the problem and this is the entire resolution I managed to come up with. Thanks @TedShifrin for the encouragement!

Given
$ v = \begin{bmatrix}a \\b \end{bmatrix} \in R^{2}$ we can solve the equation as follows:
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1, 1)\\
0& 2\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1, 1)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a \\b \end{bmatrix} = 0 \iff b \begin{bmatrix} 2\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1, 1)\\2\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) + \frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1, 1) \end{bmatrix} = 0 \iff b = 0 \lor (2\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) = -\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1, 1)) \land (2\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) = -\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1, 1))
$$
Hence, all vectors $(a, 0) \in R^{2}, \forall a \in R$ satisfy the criteria.

I am unsure if this is true or possible but given the equation it can be said that:

If $2\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial x} (1,1) = -\frac{\partial h_1} {\partial y} (1, 1) \land 2\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial x} (1,1) = -\frac{\partial h_2} {\partial y} (1, 1)$ then $Df(x, y)$ is the $2x2$ null matrix so all vectors in $R^{2}$ satisfy the criteria.

Comment: The $0$ is also a vector, since $f$ takes values in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I guess you already figured it out. Let $v=(a,b)$, then the resulting vector is b(something), so you could just choose $v=(1,0)$. You can view $f=(f_1,f_2)$ and    to show $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial v}(0,1)=0$ for both $i=1,2$. It is actually equivalent to what you have done.

Comment: By the way, you use ^2 to get a superscript.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much @TedShifrin, I think I was having some difficulties wrapping my head around that because all the material provided always had vector derivatives always resulting in scalars, I forgot this was a vector field

Comment: Everything you wrote was correct and well done.

Comment: @Koobe thank you very much! I wasn't used to this notation

Comment: Thank you very much! @TedShifrin

Comment: Why don't you write an answer with as complete an answer as you can give? Are multiples of $(1,0)$ the only possibilities?